# How to recognize backlit of an Asus UX31E keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, laptop, backlight

I replaced the keyboard in my *Asus UX31E* with one from later *UX31A*. The only technical difference between the two is that the latter has keyboard backlight and uses Fn + F3 / F4 for this.

However, I can't get keyboard backlight to work, the module is not loaded and the function keys are not registered in `xev`, `showkey` or `acpi_listen`.

How can I find the device name for the keyboard?

Is there any way to force Ubuntu to recognize my keyboard as UX31A?

I'm looking for further ways to troubleshoot this issue.

**Additional information**

According to the [Community Help Wiki for UX31A](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbookPrime#Keyboard), keyboard backlight should work after 13.04. This is where the module is for *UX31A* users:

```
/sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

`lsmod | grep -i asus`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
asus_nb_wmi            16990  0 
asus_wmi               24191  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          13948  1 asus_wmi
wmi                    19177  1 asus_wmi
video                  19476  2 i915,asus_wmi
```

`dmesg | grep -i asus`:

```
[    0.000000] DMI: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. UX31E/UX31E, BIOS UX31E.214 08/14/2012
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 00000000000f0430 000024 (v02 _ASUS_)
[    0.000000] ACPI: XSDT 00000000baffee18 000074 (v01 _ASUS_ Notebook 06222004 MSFT 00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 00000000baf9ad98 0000F4 (v04 _ASUS_ Notebook 06222004 MSFT 00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 00000000baf87018 012544 (v01 _ASUS_ Notebook 00000000 INTL 20091112)
[    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 00000000baffdf18 0000CC (v02 _ASUS_ Notebook 06222004 MSFT 00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DBGP 00000000baffff18 000034 (v01 _ASUS_ Notebook 06222004 MSFT 00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: ECDT 00000000bafe4b18 0000C1 (v01 _ASUS_ Notebook 06222004 AMI. 00000003)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SLIC 00000000baf9be18 000176 (v01 _ASUS_ Notebook 06222004 ASUS 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET 00000000bafe5d18 000038 (v01 _ASUS_ Notebook 06222004 AMI. 00000003)
[    0.000000] ACPI: MCFG 00000000bafe5c98 00003C (v01 _ASUS_ Notebook 06222004 MSFT 00000097)
[   11.529045] asus_wmi: ASUS WMI generic driver loaded
[   11.530590] asus_wmi: Initialization: 0x1
[   11.530629] asus_wmi: BIOS WMI version: 7.6
[   11.530683] asus_wmi: SFUN value: 0xa0877
[   11.531584] input: Asus WMI hotkeys as /devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/input/input17
[   11.633914] asus_wmi: Disabling ACPI video driver
```

Here's the entire entire `lshw` on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/qLmeP4vy).

Comment: Did you modified the grub?

Comment: I'm willing to bet that the backlight is simply not being powered. Perhaps there is a special connector for it and your motherboard lacks it.

Comment: the firmware might not even be written to use it. Interesting question, but it might be a lost cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching I have found a definitive answer on the ASUS support FAQ's.

http://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1003856

> No, unfortunately, the UX31E models do not support backlit keyboards.

Comment: Then terdon was correct about it being a motherboard issue. Good find! It never occurred to me they'd write about that.